# PHP Pagination Display

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I'm using bootstrap pagination, and a combination PHP/mysql method of displaying my results, (ex. results.php?results=1 for each page).  This is working fine, but actually displaying the pagination div at the bottom of my page, i.e. which one is active, whether or not you can click the following or preceding items (if there actually are results on those pages)

So I've done a specific case for just about every combination I could think of that would affect anything, but it is certainly not efficient.  Can anyone suggest a better way to do it?  Some of the cases will be obvious, like if I'm on page one, I don't want to show page 0 and -1 in the pagination, others are less obvious, like if I'm on page 3, and there are no more pages, I want page 3 to be in the middle, as there are 5 numbers displayed, but you should not be able to click on 4 and 5.

I'm using an exact replica of the plugin showed [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination) except I've added left and right increase / decrease by one in addition to the first / last page.

```
    <div id="pagination" style="width: 340px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
<? if ($results == 1) {   ?>    
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-left"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-left"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#"><? echo $results; ?> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < $num_res) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results + 1); ?>"><? echo $results + 1; ?></a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res * 2)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results + 2); ?>"><? echo $results + 2; ?></a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res * 3)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results + 3); ?>"><? echo $results + 3; ?></a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res * 4)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results + 4); ?>"><? echo $results + 4; ?></a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results + 1); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($last_page); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-right"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
  <? } ?>
  <? if ($results == 2) { ?>    
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".(1); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-left"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results - 1); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-left"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results - 1); ?>"><? echo $results - 1; ?></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results); ?>"><? echo $results; ?> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res * 2)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results + 1); ?>"><? echo $results + 1; ?></a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res * 3)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results + 2); ?>"><? echo $results + 2; ?></a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res * 3)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results + 3); ?>"><? echo $results + 3; ?></a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res * 3)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results + 1); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res * 3)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($last_page); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-right"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
  <? } ?>
  <? if (($results == 3) && (($last_page == 3))) { ?>   
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".(1); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-left"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results - 1); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-left"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results - 2); ?>"><? echo $results - 2; ?> </a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results - 1); ?>"><? echo $results - 1; ?></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results); ?>"><? echo $results; ?><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res * 3)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results + 1); ?>"><? echo $results + 1; ?></a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res * 3)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results + 2); ?>"><? echo $results + 2; ?></a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res * 3)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results + 1); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res * 3)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($last_page); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-right"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
  <? } ?>
    <? if (($results > 2) && ($results < ($last_page - 1))) { ?>    
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".(1); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-left"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results - 1); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-left"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results - 2); ?>"><? echo $results - 2; ?> </a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results - 1); ?>"><? echo $results - 1; ?></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results); ?>"><? echo $results; ?><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results + 1); ?>"><? echo $results + 1; ?></a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results + 2); ?>"><? echo $results + 2; ?></a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res * 3)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results + 1); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res * 3)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($last_page); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-right"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
  <? } ?>
    <? if (($results > 2) && ($results == ($last_page - 1))) { ?>   
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".(1); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-left"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results - 1); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-left"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results - 3); ?>"><? echo $results - 3; ?></a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results - 2); ?>"><? echo $results - 2; ?></a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results - 1); ?>"><? echo $results - 1; ?></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results ); ?>"><? echo $results ?><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results + 1); ?>"><? echo $results + 1; ?></a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res * 3)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results + 1); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li <?if ($num_rows < ($num_res * 3)) { echo "class=\"disabled\""; } ?>><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($last_page); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-right"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
  <? } ?>
   <? if (($results > 2) && ($results == $last_page) && ($results != 3)){ ?>    
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".(1); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-left"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results - 1); ?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-left"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results - 4); ?>"><? echo $results - 4; ?> </a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results - 3); ?>"><? echo $results - 3; ?></a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results - 2); ?>"><? echo $results - 2; ?></a></li>
  <li><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results - 1); ?>"><? echo $results - 1; ?></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="<? echo $url."&results=".($results ); ?>"><? echo $results ?><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-right"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
  <? } ?>
</div>
```

If no one feels like helping with the first portion, I understand, it works as it is as far as I can tell.

But I also am wondering if there's a way that on my `class="disabled"`, I can remove the hrefs?  Or do I just have to put an if statement on every one?  Thanks.

Edit: Based on @Scopey's recommendations.  I changed a few things as I saw fit, as well as a couple variable names.

```
$numberOfPages = ceil($num_rows / $num_res);
$numberOfPages = (int)$numberOfPages;

$url = explode('&', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
function myFilter($string) {
return strpos($string, 'results=') === false;
}

$url = array_filter($url, 'myFilter');
$url = implode('&', $url);

?> 
<ul class="pagination">
     <li<?php if($results === $numberOfPages): ?> class="disabled"<?php endif; ?>><a href="<?php
if($results !== $numberOfPages){
    echo $url.'&results=' . 1;
} else { echo '#'; } 
?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-left"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li<?php if($results === 1): ?> class="disabled"<?php endif; ?>><a href="<?php
if($results !== 1){
    echo $url.'&results=' . ($results - 1);
} else { echo '#'; } 

?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-left"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>

<?php

// Print the pagination...
// Minimum of 5 pages in the pagination, even if there aren't 5 pages...
$pageCount = ($numberOfPages < 5) ? 5 : $numberOfPages;

// Loop through from page 1 until the last page ($pageCount)
for($i = 1; $i <= $pageCount; $i++)
{
     // Echo out just the beginning of the <li> tag as we don't yet
     // know if this needs to be disabled...
     echo '<li';
     // Added to show if current page is active
     if($i === $results) {
          echo ' class="active"';
     }
     // Check if:
     //  - This current page is greater than the amount of pages of
     //    results we have
     //  - OR, this is the currently selected page
     if($i > $numberOfPages || $results === $i)
     {
          // <li> tag needs the disabled class....
          echo ' class="disabled"';
     }
     // Finish the <li> tag and start generating the link
     echo '><a href="';
     // Opposite logic from above... Only if this is a page we know about
     // AND this is not the current page.
     if($i < $numberOfPages && $results !== $i)
     {
          // The link will be your page, with the get param, and the
          // current page number we're printing
          echo $url.'&results=' . $i;
     }
     else
     {
          // Otherwise just a # (no link)
          echo '#';
     }
     // Finish this page... Print the page number ($i)
     echo '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
}
?>
    <li<?php if($results === $numberOfPages): ?> class="disabled"<?php endif; ?>><a href="<?php
if($results !== $numberOfPages){
    echo $url.'&results=' . ($results + 1);
} else { echo '#'; } 
?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>
 <li<?php if($results === $numberOfPages): ?> class="disabled"<?php endif; ?>><a href="<?php
if($results !== $numberOfPages){
    echo $url.'&results=' . $numberOfPages;
} else { echo '#'; } 
?>">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-double-right"></i>&nbsp;</a></li>

<?php
```

@Scobey, this works great, as intended, and same as my original post, except for a couple things.  In my example, I was able to get the current page in the middle of the .  For example,  << 1 | 2 | **3** | 4 | 5 >>, that's why I had so many different statements with +1 and -1, +2, -2 etc.

Second, my intention was to display 5 page options at all times, not just a minimum of five.  So if I was on page 6, I would only see << 4 | 5 | **6** | 7 | 8 >>, not 1-8.  It may not be necessary to do it this way, it's a nice to have.  But, I don't want to get to a point where I have over 50 different page numbers in the pagination.

Comment: how can any one write code like that? or read it.

Comment: That's why I'm asking for help here.  As far as reading it, it's just 6 of the exact same UL, with different results.

Comment: well you don't need the nearly identical blocks, a function\loop would decease this to a total of 6 lines

Comment: I know it's really hacked together, because I kinda just started from the first and kept adding as I saw needed, but I don't see how I could possibly get it down to 6 lines.  And I'm not trying to argue, as you can see from my reputation I'm not an expert.  Using a loop, I just see too many possible variables here with shifting the page numbers, and enabling / disabling buttons.  I'm trying to have current page be in the middle, unless you're on page one or two, or the second to last or last page.  It would be easier if my pagination only displayed 3 numbers.

Comment: Do you really always want exactly 5 results? So there are no cases with more than 5 or exactly 1 result? Or have you choosen five because it's in the example of bootstrap? In most use cases of pagination you only show the pages which are available.

Comment: As of this post, I do always want exactly 5 results to show in the pagination.  I may have more than 5 pages worth of results, in that case I'll just show pages << 7|8|9| **10** |11|12 >>.  If it's less, 3 for example, the way I have it now, it will show 1-5, but 4 and 5 will be `class=disabled`.  I'm starting to think this isn't the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Generally dynamic pagination works only when you have a few things

1. A count of all possible results (total)
2. An amount of results you want to show per page
3. The current page number
4. Information about the results that should appear on this page.

Imagine that you have a database table called `Results` that has a whole bunch of results you want on your paginated page

**1. Count of all possible results**

This is achievable with a simple SQL statement like:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Results
```

**2. Amount per page**

This is a value you get to decide yourself.

**3. The current page number**

This is usually 1 by default, but when the pagination is changed, it gets passed through as a get parameter.

**4. A slice of results from the table**

Achievable with:

```
SELECT * FROM Results LIMIT 0, 20
```

This example retrieves the first 20 results in our results table...

**5. The pagination**

Now, using 20 results as a default "count per page"

```
$countPerPage = 20;

// Get the total number of results
$result = pg_query('SELECT count(*) FROM Results'); // I'm using PostgreSQL for this example
$totalResultCount = (int)pg_fetch_result($result, 0, 0);

// The ceil function will round floats up.
$numberOfPages = ceil($totalResultCount / $countPerPage);

// Check if we have a page number in the _GET parameters
if(!empty($_GET) && isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
}
else
{
    $page = 1;
}

// Check that the page is within our bounds
if($page < 0)
{
    $page = 1;
}
elseif($page > $numberOfPages)
{
    $page = $numberOfPages;
}

// Build the query for the results...
$query = 'SELECT * FROM Results LIMIT ' . ($page - 1) * $countPerPage . ', ' . $countPerPage;

$results = pg_fetch_all(pg_query($query));

// Deal with printing your results etc...

?>
<ul class="pagination">
    <li<?php if($page === 1): ?> class="disabled"<?php endif; ?>><a href="<?php
if($page !== 1){
    echo 'page.php?page=' . $page - 1;
} else { echo '#'; } 
?>">&laquo;</a></li>
<?php

// Print the pagination...
// Minimum of 5 pages in the pagination, even if there aren't 5 pages...
$pageCount = ($numberOfPages < 5) ? 5 : $numberOfPages;

// Loop through from page 1 until the last page ($pageCount)
for($i = 1; $i < $pageCount; $i++)
{
     // Echo out just the beginning of the <li> tag as we don't yet
     // know if this needs to be disabled...
     echo '<li';

     // Check if:
     //  - This current page is greater than the amount of pages of
     //    results we have
     //  - OR, this is the currently selected page
     if($i > $numberOfPages || $page === $i)
     {
          // <li> tag needs the disabled class....
          echo ' class="disabled"';
     }
     // Finish the <li> tag and start generating the link
     echo '><a href="';
     // Opposite logic from above... Only if this is a page we know about
     // AND this is not the current page.
     if($i < $numberOfPages && $page !== $i)
     {
          // The link will be your page, with the get param, and the
          // current page number we're printing
          echo 'page.php?page=' . $i;
     }
     else
     {
          // Otherwise just a # (no link)
          echo '#';
     }
     // Finish this page... Print the page number ($i)
     echo '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
}
?>
<ul class="pagination">
    <li<?php if($page === $numberOfPages): ?> class="disabled"<?php endif; ?>><a href="<?php
if($page !== $numberOfPages){
    echo 'page.php?page=' . $page + 1;
} else { echo '#'; } 
?>">&raquo;</a></li>
<?php
```

**Disclaimer**

I just sat here and wrote this, I have not tested it, but the general idea is there. Hopefully it makes sense. I'm running out of time and don't have time to test or improve it, but if you're interested I might fix it up later.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply!!

I might not have made clear in my original post, the actual pagination, displaying and parsing results is working fine.  I have a variable (`$results`) that fetches the page number.  I also have at the top of my php 
`$num_res = 10; $offset = ($results - 1) * $num_res;` which determines my MySQL query `LIMIT`.  `$num_res` is a user selectable option (10 results, 25, 100)

I'll take a crack at converting your loop to work on my page.

Comment: I added some comments to the loop to hopefully make it a little clearer what's going on. I just want to recommend that you do scrap what you have written in your original post. I don't want to sound harsh but the best code is that which is extendible. You want to write something, and not have be broken by user input. Imagine, in your example, if you allowed an average Joe to add more results... You would have to update your pagination every single time another page was needed.

Comment: Okay, I've modified your code to work with mine.  Please see my edit in my original post for my comments, if you get the time.  Thanks again for your reply.